# Coding issue in folder path

Tags: python, encoding, utf, cyrillic

I have a folder path which has some cyrillic letter which stop the process of another script. I need to get a folder path without cyrillic letters but python doesn't return it.

The folder is `C:\Users\PereverzevPV\Documents\Инв`.

I have:

```
import os
folder = os.getcwd()
print folder
```

The output is empty no matter what coding I set. I need to get

```
'C:\\Users\\PereverzevPV\\Documents\\\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb2'
```

Comment: add on the first of your script : # coding: UTF-8

Comment: Added. Still get this `C:\Users\PereverzevPV\Documents\Инв`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
# coding: UTF-8

import os

os.getcwd().encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

We Need To Encode The CWD then to Decode Him

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a file path in unicode than a return will also be in unicode:

```
>>> for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(u"D:\\SO"):
    print dirnames


[u'\u0142', u'\u0418\u043d\u0432']
```

Maybe you could use that and later reassemble the path as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Your poblem is, that you are not escaping `\`: `\U`, `\P`, `\D` or `\И` are not valid utf-8 chars.

```
# coding: UTF-8

txt = r"C:\Users\PereverzevPV\Documents\Инв"
txt = "C:\\Users\\PereverzevPV\\Documents\\Инв"

esc_txt = txt.encode('utf-8')

print(esc_txt)
```

Comment: it gives an error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)`